# MSBuild /p:GenerateAppInstallerFile creates an .appinstaller file with an old schema

Tags: azure-pipelines

In my build pipeline (Azure DevOps) I have added `/p:GenerateAppInstallerFile` in order to automatically create an .appinstaller file for MSIX deployment.

The file is generated by an MS agent, running on the latest Windows version:

```
  pool:
    # need a windows agent
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'


 - task: MSBuild@1
    displayName: MSBuild
    inputs:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      platform: 'x64'
      configuration: 'Release'
      msbuildArguments: '/restore 
                        /p:GenerateAppInstallerFile=true'
```

but the generated file uses an obsolete schema:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2017/2"
```

This format does not support the auto-updates features I want to use.

What I need is the new schema:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2018"
```

How do I make the MS agent generate the file in the newest format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a task that modifies the generated file:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Modify generated .appinstaller file'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
  $newSchema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2018"

  $localFilePath = "$(installerBuildOutputPath)\${{ parameters.installerProjectName}}.appinstaller"
  Write-Host "Loading file as text: " $localFilePath

  $fileContent = Get-Content $localFilePath          
  
  # First replace the schema with the newest one. Using normal text replace here since Xml doc methods gave exceptions.
  # using text replace is easier than manipulating xml nodes, but causes problems with indentation...          
  $fileContent = $fileContent.Replace("http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2017/2", $newSchema);

  $fileContent = $fileContent.Replace(
      'HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0"', 
      'HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" ShowPrompt="true" UpdateBlocksActivation="true"');

  $fileContent = $fileContent.Replace(
      '</UpdateSettings>', 
      '<ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion>true</ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion>
      </UpdateSettings>');

  Write-Host "New file contents: $fileContent";     

  if($fileContent -like "*UpdateBlocksActivation*" -and $fileContent -like "*$newSchema*")
  {
    Write-Host "Replaced namespace (xmlns) with newest schema version. Modified UpdateSettings." 
    $fileContent | Set-Content $localFilePath
  }
  else 
  {
    Write-Host "Text replacement failed." 
    exit 1
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is one of the top results for this, I'm sharing the solution I found.

You need to add a custom Package.installer file to your project. If you use "Add Item" in Visual Studio, it will create a file with the old template, and you just need to update it to the newer version of the schema. The name has to be "Package.installer"; the .targets file is using %(Identity) to match against it.

Details on Microsoft's github are here: https://github.com/microsoft/devops-for-windows-apps/issues/25#issuecomment-499680689