Change UpdateSettings eg. OnLaunch HoursBetweenUpdateChecks WITHOUT creating a whole appinstaller file
I would like to change 1 value of the automatic update setting
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/update-settings
The OnLaunch HoursBetweenUpdateChecks Property from the default value 24 to 0.
(Yes, I actually want the app to check for updates OnLaunch, on every launch, without a delay of 24 hours)
BUT as it would seem, I would need to create the whole appinstaller file, with all bundles/dependencies and so on, see example here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/how-to-create-appinstaller-file#example-of-an-app-installer-file
This seems like total overkill to change just one field.
So, before going down this rabbit hole, I wanted to ask is there another way?
And I struggle to understand...

Why doesn't Visual Studio/MAUI workload generate an appinstaller file to be edited like it creates a *.pubxml file?
Why can't I define "simple" properties in the *.pubxml file?
Why are there even two different files in the first place a *.pubxml and *.appinstaller?


Have you tried following the doc Publish the project?  The  Configure update settings dialog, is where you configure how often the app should check for updates.

@LiqunShen-MSFT - maybe I misunderstood the dialogue, but it seems its either check on launch OR check periodically, hence the radio button

@LiqunShen-MSFT - so IMHO the dialog should produce AutomaticBackgroundTask and not OnLaunch

@LiqunShen-MSFT - so after 24 hours the default value of HoursBetweenUpdateChecks, nothing happened, no update, no prompt, just nothing... after some googling - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73237410 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76927140 - it seems I have to create the *.appinstaller file myself... - so yeah... kinda annoying, that I now need to learn the whole *.appinstaller syntax/settings, and manually adjust the file regularly (eg. new autocrementing version number, new dependencies...)

Here is the GitHub issue, .appinstaller file not generated when publishing .Net Maui App #9985. This issue appears to be a problem with Visual Studio. You may use VS Feedback Tool to report the issue.

@LiqunShen-MSFT - have a look at my answer the missing *.appinstaller file is unrelated to visual studio

@LiqunShen-MSFT - update worked BUT it updated automatically without prompting the user

@LiqunShen-MSFT - (cont) according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/update-settings there should be settings like ShowPrompt/UpdateBlocksActivation which I wanted both to be true... BUT sadly setting those settings in *.csproj the *.appinstaller file didn't pick those settings up, after round 2 of going down the rabbit hole I am running into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113722 - and I aswell have a *.appinstaller file with an outdated schema which refused the ShowPrompt/UpdateBlocksActivation information...

@LiqunShen-MSFT - my current mindset: cries in agony

If an *.appinstaller file is generated seems to be determined on the msbuild property /p:AppxBundle=Never, is it set to Never an *.appinstaller file is generated.
The current version of Visual Studio has a "Publish" User Interface which lacks a setting for this:
From the menu Build --> Publish Selection

For comparison how it seems to have looked at some point of time look at this image:

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/windowsappsdk/issues/1821#issuecomment-1100464213
There is no option for "Generate app bundle" anymore.
This option can be set in the csproj file eg.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>

        <!-- add this line -->
        <AppxBundle>Never</AppxBundle> 

Or if you are using command line or Visual Studio Code's terminal to publish the app, you will have to use.
dotnet publish -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 /p:AppxBundle=Never

Instead of only
dotnet publish -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0

When /p:AppxBundle=Never is NOT set, and you have a look at msbuild output, when enabled Diagnostic.

You can see the output

Target "GenerateAppInstallerForPackage" skipped, due to false
condition; ('$(GenerateAppInstallerFile)' == 'true' AND
'$(ProduceAppxBundle)' == 'false') was evaluated as ('True' == 'true'
AND 'True' == 'false').

So for what ever reason the Target GenerateAppInstallerForPackage will only execute if ProduceAppxBundle is false.
When you search for ProduceAppxBundle you will find this:

Source: https://github.com/appveyor/ci/blob/a6f7fdb58ef7fff9457d644840bb332c280151e7/scripts/hot-fixes/vs2017-uwp-scale-100-fix/Microsoft.AppxPackage.Targets#L2481
As you can see ProduceAppyBundle is only false when AppxBundle is specified as Never.
Note: I couldn't figure out what $(_MultipleQualifiersPerDimensionFound) does, and why it may result to false on my machine and maybe true on other machines.
With AppxBundle=Never the msbuild output will have outputs like this ( and many more )

Added Item(s):
PackagingDirectoryWrites=bin\AppPackages\MauiApp6_0.0.9.0_x64_Test
Set Property:
AppInstallerPackageOutputFile=bin\AppPackages\MauiApp6_0.0.9.0_x64_Test\MauiApp6_0.0.9.0_x64.msix
Using "WinAppSdkGenerateAppInstallerFile" task from assembly
"C:\repoPackages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.5.240311000\buildTransitive..\tools\net472\Microsoft.Build.Msix.dll". Aufgabenparameter:AppxUri=bin\AppPackages\MauiApp6_0.0.9.0_x64_Test\MauiApp6_0.0.9.0_x64.msix
Aufgabenparameter:ProjectFileDir=C:\Users\rfa\source\repos\MauiApp6\MauiApp6
Aufgabenparameter:AppxPackageDir=bin\AppPackages
Aufgabenparameter:AppInstallerUri=C:\rfa\MauiApp6

On a newly created MAUI application WITHOUT using AppxBundle=Never, the resulted output is this:


WITH using AppxBundle=Never, the resulted output is this:


Note:
Some questions I had are obsolte now, because after going down the rabbit hole, I found that the publish user interface creates the *.pubxml file AND sets some properties in the *.csproj file.
Namely those:
<GenerateAppInstallerFile>True</GenerateAppInstallerFile>
<AppxPackageSigningEnabled>True</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
<PackageCertificateThumbprint>xyz</PackageCertificateThumbprint>
<AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>SHA256</AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>
<AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>True</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
<AppxSymbolPackageEnabled>False</AppxSymbolPackageEnabled>
<GenerateTestArtifacts>True</GenerateTestArtifacts>
<AppInstallerUri>C:\rfa\MauiApp6</AppInstallerUri>
<HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>0</HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>

So there is no need for me, now that autogenerating the *.appinstaller works, to create a manual *.appinstaller file I can adjust the settings in the *.csproj file.
Though, personally I find it confusing that some properties are defined in the *.pubxml file and others in the *.csproj file.
Here a comparison screenshot, on the right a newly created MAUI project and on the left a MAUI Project where you have run from menu bar Build --> Publish Selection

